# Problem with baking cavity map

Tags: texturing

I'm working with blender 2.8. I'm learning how baking textures of a sculpting model. I succeed baking, normals and ambient occlusion maps, but I don't succeed baking cavity map.
I watched several tutorials, and I think I did the steps, but it doesn't work, so maybe I did something wrong.

I created a new texture: WOODPLANKcavity
[image: Here is the LOW POLY woodplank]
Here is the HIGH POLY woodplank
[image: Here is the HIGH POLY woodplank]

I went to edit mode and selected HIGH POLY first, then LOW POLY. I Did what I circled in the screenshot.[image: I Did what I circled in the screenshot]

Finally, the error message [image: the error message]

I hope, I gave enough informations. If anybody needs more details, please let me know, I'll answer. I'm waiting for help, I'm really gonna giving up this project if I don't find solution...thanks

Comment: Have you tried selecting the high poly object and then the low poly object in *object mode*?

Comment: It's working!! thank you!! I didn't imagine it was that, because in the tutorials they were in edit mode...Just because of one little thing... Thanks for your help.